# Complex Analysis - Integration on an arc

Tags: integration, analysis

I'm quite new to complex analysis, I'm studying it for the first time at university over the last few weeks. So far it's going okay, but there is one homework question that's really causing me trouble. It is as follows:

A curve $C$ is defined by the function $\eta : [0, 2] \to \mathbb{C}$ where
$$
\eta(t) = \frac{3}{4}\left(1+\frac{1}{7}\sin(9\pi t)\right)(3t+4)e^{i\pi (t+1/2)}.
$$
Evaluate the contour integral $\int_C \frac{1}{z} dz$.

There is a hint in the question saying that Cauchy's Integral Formula will be useful if you can construct a closed contour that includes $C$ as an arc, but I have no idea how CIF could be included to evaluate the integral. I honestly don't have much clue on where to go from the get-go, so cannot provide much in terms of what I've tried. I've considered using the antiderivative, Log, but feel like that's wrong.

Thank you for any help or hints that could be provided to push me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The curve $\eta$ begins at $3i$, goes around the origin in the direct direction and ends at $\frac{15}2i$. Therefore, if $\delta(t)=(1-t)\frac{15}2i+3ti$, then, by Cauchy's Integral Formula,$$\int_\eta\frac1z\,\mathrm dz+\int_\delta\frac1z\,\mathrm dz=2\pi i,$$and therefore$$\int_\eta\frac1z\,\mathrm dz=2\pi i-\int_\delta\frac1z\,\mathrm dz.$$And this last integral is easy to compute.

Comment: Thank you for this! My only question is that I was taught that the function to be integrated (so in this case, $\frac{1}{z}$) had to be analytic on the boundary/region defined by the contour. This contour includes $z=0$, so our function isn't analytic on the domain. Is there any problem there or am I misunderstanding something else?

Comment: There is no $t$ in the interval such that $\eta (t) = 0.$  The function is everywhere on the contour and has its singularity in the interior of the contour.

Comment: So say hypothetically that the function $\eta$ did have a $t$ such that $\eta(t) = 0$ at some point. Then we still say that $\frac{1}{z}$ or $\frac{1}{\eta}$ is analytic but just on the interval for $t \in [0, 2]$?

Comment: This contour dos *not* contain $0$. For each $t\in[0,2]$, $|\eta(t)|>2$.

Comment: Sorry, yes I phrased my question badly... what I mean is that for CIF to apply, $f(z) = \frac{1}{z}$ needs to be analytic on and inside the contour, but it isn't analytic inside the contour since it contains $z = 0$.

Comment: That is just plain false. Where do you [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula) (for instance) that $f$ has to be analytic *inside* the contour?

Comment: It doesn't say it there, but in the notes I was given and another set of notes they say
1) "Suppose $C$ is a simple closed curve and the function f(z) is analytic on a region containing $C$ and its interior."
2) "Suppose $f$ is analytic in a domain $D$, and for a point $a \in D$ and $0 < r \in \mathbb{R}$ we have that $B$ being the ball $B = \{z : |z-a| \leq r \}$ is contained in $D$. Let $C = \partial B$, oriented anticlockwise."

Both cases in my limited understanding just make it seem like it needs to be analytic EVERYWHERE on and inside the contour. Is that wrong?

Comment: @JoelD77 Just plain wrong.

Comment: Okay good to know.. so then what is the requirement of $f(z)$then for CIF to apply? I'm quite confused by it. Just to be analytic at some point in the contour, or...?

Comment: The function that has to be analytic inside the countour is the numerator. Your numerator is the constant function $1$, which is obviously analytic. The fact that $\frac1z$ is undefined at $0$ is not relevant. Actualy, whenever we apply Cauchy's integral formula, there will alwyas be some point at which the function that we are integrating is undefined, which is usually withen the region bounded by the contour.

Answer (score 0):

To complete José's answer, here is the plot in Wolfram Alpha, which shows the curve turning around the origin, needing just a segment from $3i$ to $\frac {15} 2 i$ to complete a full loop:

[image: image in Wolfram Alpha]

[curve in Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot%20%28Re%283%2F4%281%2B1%2F7sin%289%20pi%20t%29%29%283t%2B4%29e%5E%28i%20pi%20%28t%2B1%2F2%29%29%29%2C%20Im%283%2F4%281%2B1%2F7sin%289%20pi%20t%29%29%283t%2B4%29e%5E%28i%20pi%20%28t%2B1%2F2%29%29%29%29%20from%20t%3D0%20to%202)

The fact that it loops around the origin is given in polar coordinates by:

- $r$ is $\frac{3}{4}\left(1+\frac{1}{7}\sin(9\pi t)\right)(3t+4)$, which is real and $\ge \frac{3}{4}\left(1-\frac{1}{7})\right)4 \gt 0$
- The angle is given by $e^{iπ(t+1/2)}$, i.e. $\theta=\pi(t+1/2)$, which makes a full turn in positive direction.

Comment: Thank you for the plot! I had been wondering how to plot complex curves, and now I know.

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that the contour $C$ starts at $\eta(0)=3i$ and ends at $\frac{15}{2}i$.

$r=|\eta(t)|=\frac{3}{4}(1+\frac{1}{7}\sin(9\pi t))(3t+1)>0$ and $\theta=arg(\eta(t))=\pi(t+\frac{1}{2})$ for all $t\in [0,2]$. Notice that $arg(\eta(0))=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $arg(\eta(1))=\frac{3\pi}{2}$ so that $arg(\eta(1))-arg(\eta(0))=2\pi$! That's the key of our problem. This contour start at $3i$ rotates counter-clockwise away from the origin and ends at $\frac{15}{2}i$.

Now, let $C_2$ be the curve $\gamma(t)= (1-t)\frac{15}{2}i+t3i$ where $t\in[0,1]$which is the directed line segment from $\frac{15}{2}i$ to $3i$. Then we obtain a simple closed contour $C+C_2$.

$\int_{C+C_2}\frac{1}{z}dz=2\pi i$ by Cauchy's integral formula.

On the other hand $\int_{C+C_2}\frac{1}{z}dz=\int_{C}\frac{1}{z}dz+\int_{C_2}\frac{1}{z}dz$ hence we have $I=\int_{C}\frac{1}{z}dz=2\pi i-\int_{C_2}\frac{1}{z}dz$.

We can compute $\int_{C_2}\frac{1}{z}dz=\int_{\frac{15}{2}i}^{3i}\frac{1}{z}dz=\ln z |_{\frac{15}{2}i}^{3i}=\ln(3i)-\ln(\frac{15}{2}i)=\ln(\frac{3i}{\frac{15}{2}i})=\ln2-\ln5$.

Hence, $I=2\pi i-(\ln2-\ln5)=\ln5-\ln2+2\pi i.$